# Justification of header text

Tags: header-footer, justification, varwidth

I want my long header text to be justified. In the picture below:
[image: Illustration]
I have inserted a red line such that I want all the text to be on the right side of that line (justification). How do I achieve that? Below is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany,twoside]{book}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage[ 
left=2.5cm,
right=2.5cm, 
top=3cm, 
bottom=3cm,
headheight = 3\baselineskip,
headsep = 5mm,
a4paper
]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\HRule{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1.5pt}}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hhline}
\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[OL]{\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[ER]{\rightmark}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[RE,RO]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand\headrule
    {{     \color{blue}\rule{1\headwidth}{2.5pt}%       
    }}
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \renewcommand\headrule
    {{     \color{blue}\rule{1\headwidth}{0pt}%         
    }}      
}

\pagestyle{fancy}   

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document} 
    \chapter{ABCD}
    eehehdhdhdhddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
    \pagebreak
    \section{Special keyboard characters gghthr rhrrhd fheheh fhehuw fhewiwi feiwiwd fiiwiwid fiiwiwi firiifn rokfkkvfvv fjjjeje jejeje djej}
    \LaTeX{} has many symbols at its disposal. The majority of them are within the mathematical domain as shown in \eqref{eq:1} and \eqref{eq:2}. The ten special keyboard characters are: \verb|#|, \verb|$|, \verb|%|, \verb|&|, \verb|~|, \verb|_|, \verb|^|, \verb|\| and  \verb|{}|. If you simply want the character to be printed just as any other letter, include a \verb|\ | in front of the character. For example, \verb|\$| will produce \verb|$| in your output.
    The exception to the rule is the \verb|\ | itself because \verb|\\ | has its own special meaning. A \verb|\ | is produced by typing \verb|$\backslash$| in your file. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the right mark in a `tabularx` narrower than the line width by the desired left margin (`14ex` in this example).

**UPDATE** after follow up question.

Long and short section titles.

[image: g]

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany,twoside]{book}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage[ 
left=2.5cm,
right=2.5cm, 
top=3cm, 
bottom=3cm,
headheight = 3\baselineskip,
headsep = 5mm,
a4paper
]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\HRule{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1.5pt}}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hhline}


%****************************************
\usepackage{tabularx}% added <<<<<          

\newlength{\leftspace}% for sections <<<<<<<<<
\setlength{\leftspace}{14ex}%

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\uppercase{#1}}}

\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[OL]{\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[ER]{%
        \begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\leftspace}{@{}lX}\thesection&\rightmark\end{tabularx}}% changed <<<<<<<<<<     
    \fancyfoot[RE,RO]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand\headrule{\color{blue}\rule{1\headwidth}{2.5pt}}
}
%****************************************

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \renewcommand\headrule
    {{     \color{blue}\rule{1\headwidth}{0pt}%         
    }}      
}

\pagestyle{fancy}   

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document} 
    
    \chapter{ABCD}
    
    eehehdhdhdhdddddd ddddddddddddddddddddd
    
    \pagebreak
    
    
    \section{Special keyboard characters gghthr rhrrhd fheheh fhehuw fhewiwi feiwiwd fiiwiwid fiiwiwi firiifn rokfkkvfvv fjjjeje jejeje djej}   
    
    
    \LaTeX{} has many symbols at its disposal. The majority of them are within the mathematical domain as shown in \eqref{eq:1} and \eqref{eq:2}. The ten special keyboard characters are: \verb|#|, \verb|$|, \verb|%|, \verb|&|, \verb|~|, \verb|_|, \verb|^|, \verb|\| and  \verb|{}|. If you simply want the character to be printed just as any other letter, include a \verb|\ | in front of the character. For example, \verb|\$| will produce \verb|$| in your output.
    The exception to the rule is the \verb|\ | itself because \verb|\\ | has its own special meaning. A \verb|\ | is produced by typing \verb|$\backslash$| in your file. 
    
    \clearpage
    
    \setcounter{page}{4}
    
    \section{Special keyboard characters}   
    
    Some text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I want all the text to be on the right of the red line. Just like the appearance of `\section{Special keyboard characters gghthr rhrrhd fheheh fhehuw fhewiwi feiwiwd fiiwiwid fiiwiwi firiifn rokfkkvfvv fjjjeje jejeje djej}`

Comment: @itc But it is that way now! (without a red line of course)

Comment: The words SPECIAL, HEH & ROKFKKVFVV are not aligned properly in vertical sense.

Comment: I want all my section headers to be on the right side. However, the solution you provided solves the long section headers problem. However, the short section headers are no longer on the right side of the even pages. What should I do?

Comment: @itc Please see the new updated answer. (Long and short titles)

Comment: The new update is working perfectly. However, I have loaded `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}` and I am now getting a funny output. How do I maintain this solution in the presence of this new package?

Comment: I have tried that but I'm still getting a misaligned header text. If I remove the hyphenat package, everything works well. However, I need that package for my document.

Comment: @itc Thank you for your feedback!! For the benefit of other readers if the answer meets your requirement as originally formulated, please accept by checking the green tickmark on left side of the answer. Then ask another question pointing to `hyphenat`

Comment: Noted @Simon Dispa