# Misalignment caused by hyphenat package and header text font settings

Tags: header-footer, hyphenat

## **Before loading hyphenat package and changing of header text font settings**

Before loading the `hyphenat` package and changing of header text font settings, my header text was properly aligned as shown in the picture below:
[image: Output before loading hyphenat package]
Below is the MWE which is a solution to my problem provided by @Simon Dispa at [Justification of header text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/652970/justification-of-header-text/652981?noredirect=1#comment1627483_652981).

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany,twoside]{book}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage[ 
left=2.5cm,
right=2.5cm, 
top=3cm, 
bottom=3cm,
headheight = 3\baselineskip,
headsep = 5mm,
a4paper
]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\HRule{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1.5pt}}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hhline}

\newlength{\leftspace}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\setlength{\leftspace}{18ex}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<    
\newlength{\xindent}
\settowidth{\xindent}{\thechapter.\thesection\:}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{varwidth}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[OL]{\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[ER]{\begin{varwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\leftspace}\parindent-\xindent\rightmark\end{varwidth}}% changed <<<<<
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[RE,RO]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand\headrule
    {{     \color{blue}\rule{1\headwidth}{2.5pt}%       
    }}
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \renewcommand\headrule
    {{     \color{blue}\rule{1\headwidth}{0pt}%         
    }}      
}

\pagestyle{fancy}   

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document} 

    \chapter{ABCD}
    
    eehehdhdhdhdddddd ddddddddddddddddddddd
    
    \pagebreak
    
    
    \section{Special keyboard characters gghthr rhrrhd fheheh fhehuw fhewiwi feiwiwd fiiwiwid fiiwiwi firiifn rokfkkvfvv fjjjeje jejeje djej}   
    
    
    \LaTeX{} has many symbols at its disposal. The majority of them are within the mathematical domain as shown in \eqref{eq:1} and \eqref{eq:2}. The ten special keyboard characters are: \verb|#|, \verb|$|, \verb|%|, \verb|&|, \verb|~|, \verb|_|, \verb|^|, \verb|\| and  \verb|{}|. If you simply want the character to be printed just as any other letter, include a \verb|\ | in front of the character. For example, \verb|\$| will produce \verb|$| in your output.
    The exception to the rule is the \verb|\ | itself because \verb|\\ | has its own special meaning. A \verb|\ | is produced by typing \verb|$\backslash$| in your file. 
    
    \clearpage
    
    \setcounter{page}{4}
    
    \section{Special keyboard characters}   
    
    Some text.
\end{document}
```

## **After loading hyphenat package and changing of header text font settings**

After loading the `hyphenat` package through the command `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}`, there is now a misalignment in the header text of my document. Also, I believe that the header text font setting `\myheaderfooterfont` is contributing to this misalignment. Below is the MWE, which is a solution provided by @Simon Dispa at [Justification of header text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/652970/justification-of-header-text/652981?noredirect=1#comment1627483_652981) with the `hyphenat` package loaded and font settings included.

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany,twoside]{book}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage[ 
left=2.5cm,
right=2.5cm, 
top=3cm, 
bottom=3cm,
headheight = 3\baselineskip,
headsep = 5mm,
a4paper
]{geometry}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} %added package
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\HRule{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1.5pt}}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hhline}

\newlength{\leftspace}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\setlength{\leftspace}{18ex}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<    
\newlength{\xindent}
\settowidth{\xindent}{\thechapter.\thesection\:}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{varwidth}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand*\myheaderfooterfont{\normalfont\bfseries\selectfont}%font settings


\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[OL]{\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[ER]{\begin{varwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\leftspace}\parindent-\xindent\myheaderfooterfont\rightmark\end{varwidth}}% changed <<<<<
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[RE,RO]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand\headrule
    {{     \color{blue}\rule{1\headwidth}{2.5pt}%       
    }}
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \renewcommand\headrule
    {{     \color{blue}\rule{1\headwidth}{0pt}%         
    }}      
}

\pagestyle{fancy}   

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document} 

    \chapter{ABCD}
    
    eehehdhdhdhdddddd ddddddddddddddddddddd
    
    \pagebreak
    
    
    \section{Special keyboard characters gghthr rhrrhd fheheh fhehuw fhewiwi feiwiwd fiiwiwid fiiwiwi firiifn rokfkkvfvv fjjjeje jejeje djej}   
    
    
    \LaTeX{} has many symbols at its disposal. The majority of them are within the mathematical domain as shown in \eqref{eq:1} and \eqref{eq:2}. The ten special keyboard characters are: \verb|#|, \verb|$|, \verb|%|, \verb|&|, \verb|~|, \verb|_|, \verb|^|, \verb|\| and  \verb|{}|. If you simply want the character to be printed just as any other letter, include a \verb|\ | in front of the character. For example, \verb|\$| will produce \verb|$| in your output.
    The exception to the rule is the \verb|\ | itself because \verb|\\ | has its own special meaning. A \verb|\ | is produced by typing \verb|$\backslash$| in your file. 
    
    \clearpage
    
    \setcounter{page}{4}
    
    \section{Special keyboard characters}   
    
    Some text.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `hyphenat` manual, page 2:

> The `hyphenat` package has an option called `none`. Use of this option
> prevents any hyphenation throughout the document. If TEX is prevented
> from hyphenating it may complain about bad line breaks and you may
> find bits of text sticking out into the margin. If you use this option
> you should also consider using `\sloppy` and/or `\raggedright`.

Using `\raggedright`

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany,twoside]{book}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage[ 
left=2.5cm,
right=2.5cm, 
top=3cm, 
bottom=3cm,
headheight = 3\baselineskip,
headsep = 5mm,
a4paper
]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\HRule{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1.5pt}}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hhline}

\newlength{\leftspace}% 
\setlength{\leftspace}{18ex}%
\newlength{\xindent}
\settowidth{\xindent}{\thechapter.\thesection\:}% 
\usepackage{varwidth}% 


\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[OL]{\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[ER]{\begin{varwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\leftspace}\raggedright\parindent-\xindent\rightmark\end{varwidth}}% changed <<<<<
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[RE,RO]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand\headrule
    {{     \color{blue}\rule{1\headwidth}{2.5pt}%       
    }}
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \renewcommand\headrule
    {{     \color{blue}\rule{1\headwidth}{0pt}%         
    }}      
}

\pagestyle{fancy}   

\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\raggedright % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document} 

    \chapter{ABCD}
    
    eehehdhdhdhdddddd ddddddddddddddddddddd
    
    \pagebreak
            
    \section{Special keyboard characters gghthr rhrrhd fheheh fhehuw fhewiwi feiwiwd fiiwiwid fiiwiwi firiifn rokfkkvfvv fjjjeje jejeje djej}   
    
    
    \LaTeX{} has many symbols at its disposal. The majority of them are within the mathematical domain as shown in \eqref{eq:1} and \eqref{eq:2}. The ten special keyboard characters are: \verb|#|, \verb|$|, \verb|%|, \verb|&|, \verb|~|, \verb|_|, \verb|^|, \verb|\| and  \verb|{}|. If you simply want the character to be printed just as any other letter, include a \verb|\ | in front of the character. For example, \verb|\$| will produce \verb|$| in your output.
    The exception to the rule is the \verb|\ | itself because \verb|\\ | has its own special meaning. A \verb|\ | is produced by typing \verb|$\backslash$| in your file. 
    
    \clearpage
    
    \setcounter{page}{4}
    
    \section{Special keyboard characters}       
    Some text.
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE** Changing  the font of the header

[image: f]

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany,twoside]{book}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage[ 
left=2.5cm,
right=2.5cm, 
top=3cm, 
bottom=3cm,
headheight = 3\baselineskip,
headsep = 5mm,
a4paper
]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\HRule{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1.5pt}}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hhline}


%****************************************
\usepackage{tabularx}% added <<<<<          
\newcommand*\myheaderfooterfont{\normalfont\bfseries\selectfont}%font settings <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<   

\newlength{\leftspace}% for sections <<<<<<<<<
\setlength{\leftspace}{14ex}%

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\uppercase{#1}}}

\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
    \fancyhf{}  
    \fancyhead[OL]{\myheaderfooterfont\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[ER]{\myheaderfooterfont%
        \begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\leftspace}{@{}lX}\thesection&\raggedright\rightmark\end{tabularx}}% changed <<<<<<<<<<     
    \fancyfoot[RE,RO]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand\headrule{\color{blue}\rule{1\headwidth}{2.5pt}}
}
%****************************************

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \renewcommand\headrule
    {{     \color{blue}\rule{1\headwidth}{0pt}%         
    }}      
}

\pagestyle{fancy}   

\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\raggedright % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document} 
    
    \chapter{ABCD}
    
    eehehdhdhdhdddddd ddddddddddddddddddddd
    
    \pagebreak
    
    \section{Special keyboard characters gghthr rhrrhd fheheh fhehuw fhewiwi feiwiwd fiiwiwid fiiwiwi firiifn rokfkkvfvv fjjjeje}   
    
    
    \LaTeX{} has many symbols at its disposal. The majority of them are within the mathematical domain as shown in \eqref{eq:1} and \eqref{eq:2}. The ten special keyboard characters are: \verb|#|, \verb|$|, \verb|%|, \verb|&|, \verb|~|, \verb|_|, \verb|^|, \verb|\| and  \verb|{}|. If you simply want the character to be printed just as any other letter, include a \verb|\ | in front of the character. For example, \verb|\$| will produce \verb|$| in your output.
    The exception to the rule is the \verb|\ | itself because \verb|\\ | has its own special meaning. A \verb|\ | is produced by typing \verb|$\backslash$| in your file. 
    
    \clearpage
    
    \setcounter{page}{4}
    
    \section{Special keyboard characters}       
    Some text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do I have to use `sloppy` and `raggedright` together?

Comment: @itc Only `raggedright` for the header to be equal to the section title. Or use `\sloppy`  instead for the text but not in the header.

Comment: It looks like the solution is also affected by changing the font type or boldness. Can you please check the edit I made concerning this issue

Comment: @itc Please see the updated code. You need to use `\raggedright` and change the font  both in the header and to calculate the offset.

Comment: Thank you very much once again. It worked perfectly!

Comment: I see that you have made an update to the answer. What are the effects of these changes?

Comment: @itc None. Used a better method equal to the last question answer that covers all situations: long and short titles, hanging, different fonts.