# Hanging Indentation of Chapter Header text

Tags: indentation, hangindent

Currently, the Section header text indentation is hanged thanks to @Simon Dispa solution at [Misalignment caused by hyphenat package and header text font settings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/653034/misalignment-caused-by-hyphenat-package-and-header-text-font-settings). I also want to have my Chapter header text indentation be hanged just like that of the Section. Below is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany,twoside]{book}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage[ 
left=2.5cm,
right=2.5cm, 
top=3cm, 
bottom=3cm,
headheight = 3\baselineskip,
headsep = 5mm,
a4paper
]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\HRule{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1.5pt}}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hhline}


\newcommand*\myheaderfooterfont{\normalfont\bfseries\selectfont}
\newlength{\leftspace}% 
\setlength{\leftspace}{18ex}%
\newlength{\xindent}
\settowidth{\xindent}{\myheaderfooterfont\thechapter.\thesection\:}
\usepackage{varwidth}% 


\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[OL]{\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[ER]{\begin{varwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\leftspace}\myheaderfooterfont\raggedright\parindent-\xindent\rightmark\end{varwidth}}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[RE,RO]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand\headrule
    {{     \color{blue}\rule{1\headwidth}{2.5pt}%       
    }}
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \renewcommand\headrule
    {{     \color{blue}\rule{1\headwidth}{0pt}%         
    }}      
}

\pagestyle{fancy}   

\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\raggedright

\begin{document} 
    %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<added
    \frontmatter
    \chapter*{ABC}
    \markboth{ABC}{ABC}
    eeeheeyeyeyeyeyeeyeye
    \section*{DEG}
    dddheheheheheheheehehehe
    \pagebreak
    \section*{KJ}
    ddhheheheheheehehehheheheheheh
    \pagebreak
    \section*{KDH}
    dhddhhehehehehehehehehehehe

    \mainmatter
    %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<added
    \chapter{ABCD ffhfgrhr ejejejeje fhfhfhf ehehehehe dhddhdhellgl rkttkgkhihi eeeejejwnwn hhlhlnnmgjgj rjrrjoaoaoao rjjrjrrrj wwjwwwjwjw}
    
    eehehdhdhdhdddddd ddddddddddddddddddddd
    
    \pagebreak
    
    \section{Special keyboard characters gghthr rhrrhd fheheh fhehuw fhewiwi feiwiwd fiiwiwid fiiwiwi firiifn rokfkkvfvv fjjjeje jejeje djej}   
    
    
    \LaTeX{} has many symbols at its disposal. The majority of them are within the mathematical domain as shown in \eqref{eq:1} and \eqref{eq:2}. The ten special keyboard characters are: \verb|#|, \verb|$|, \verb|%|, \verb|&|, \verb|~|, \verb|_|, \verb|^|, \verb|\| and  \verb|{}|. If you simply want the character to be printed just as any other letter, include a \verb|\ | in front of the character. For example, \verb|\$| will produce \verb|$| in your output.
    The exception to the rule is the \verb|\ | itself because \verb|\\ | has its own special meaning. A \verb|\ | is produced by typing \verb|$\backslash$| in your file. 
    
    \clearpage
    
    Special keyboard characters dhgdgdg dgdgdgdg ggdgdgd egegegege dgddgdgd eggegegeg dgdgdgdgd egegegeg dggeieieirr tktii43iwje rfrhrhrhr gtktotyiyighgjgj fkf      
Some text.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** Changing the header font.

Try this code.
[image: aa]

[image: bb]

[image: zz]

**Last update:** matching spaces and taller `headheight`.

[image: cc]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex    
\documentclass[12pt,openany,twoside]{book}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage[ 
left=2.5cm,
right=2.5cm, 
top=3cm, 
bottom=3cm,
headheight = 3.5\baselineskip,%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
headsep = 5mm,
a4paper
]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\HRule{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1.5pt}}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hhline} 

\usepackage{helvet}%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

%****************************************
\usepackage{tabularx}% added <<<<<      
\newcommand*\myheaderfooterfont{\sffamily\bfseries\selectfont}  

\newlength{\leftspace}% for sections <<<<<<<<<
\setlength{\leftspace}{20ex}%set

\newlength{\Lheader}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\uppercase{#1}}{}}% added <<<<<<<<<<<
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\uppercase{#1}}}% added <<<<<<<<<<<

\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
    \fancyhf{}  
    \fancyhead[OL]{\myheaderfooterfont%
        \ifnum\value{chapter}>0%
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lX}\uppercase{Chapter~\thechapter}&\raggedright\leftmark\end{tabularx}% changed <<<<<<<<<<
            \else\raggedright\leftmark\relax\fi}
        \fancyhead[ER]{\myheaderfooterfont%
                \settowidth{\Lheader}{\thesection\hspace*{12pt}\rightmark}  
                \ifnum\value{chapter}>0%
                \ifdim\Lheader>\linewidth%          
                \begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\leftspace}{@{}lX} \thesection &\raggedright\rightmark\end{tabularx}%
                \else\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}} \thesection &\raggedright\rightmark\end{tabular}%
                \fi\else\hfill\raggedright\rightmark\relax\fi
    }% changed <<<<<
                
    \fancyfoot[RE,RO]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand\headrule{\color{blue}\rule{1\headwidth}{2.5pt}}
}
%****************************************

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \renewcommand\headrule
    {{     \color{blue}\rule{1\headwidth}{0pt}%         
    }}      
}

\pagestyle{fancy}   

\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\raggedright %  important with  none hyphenat + none !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

\begin{document} 
    
    \frontmatter
    \chapter*{ABC}
    
    \markboth{ABC1}{ABC2}
    
    eeeheeyeyeyeyeyeeyeye
    \section*{DEG}
    dddheheheheheheheehehehe
    \pagebreak
    \section*{KJ}
    ddhheheheheheehehehheheheheheh
    \pagebreak
    \section*{KDH}
    dhddhhehehehehehehehehehehe
    
    \mainmatter

    \chapter{ABCD ffhfgrhr ejejejeje fhfhfhf ehehehehe dhddhdhellgl rkttkgkhihi eeeejejwnwn hhlhlnnmgjgj rjrrjoaoaoao  }        
    eehehdhdhdhdddddd ddddddddddddddddddddd     
        
    \newpage                
    \section{Special keyboard characters gghthr rhrrhd fheheh fhehuw fhewiwi feiwiwd fiiwiwid fiiwiwi}  

    \LaTeX{} hasmany symbols at its disposal. The majority of them are within the mathematical domain as shown in \eqref{eq:1} and \eqref{eq:2}. The ten special keyboard characters are: \verb|#|, \verb|$|, \verb|%|, \verb|&|, \verb|~|, \verb|_|, \verb|^|, \verb|\| and  \verb|{}|. If you simply want the character to be printed just as any other letter, include a \verb|\ | in front of the character. For example, \verb|\$| will produce \verb|$| in your output.
    The exception to the rule is the \verb|\ | itself because \verb|\\ | has its own special meaning. A \verb|\ | is produced by typing \verb|$\backslash$| in your file.       
    \newpage        
    \section{Special keyboard characters}       
    Special keyboard characters dhgdgdg dgdgdgdg ggdgdgd egegegege dgddgdgd eggegegeg dgdgdgdgd egegegeg dggeieieirr tktii43iwje rfrhrhrhr gtktotyiyighgjgj fkf     
    \newpage        
    Special keyboard characters dhgdgdg dgdgdgdg ggdgdgd egegegege dgddgdgd eggegegeg dgdgdgdgd egegegeg dggeieieirr tktii43iwje rfrhrhrhr gtktotyiyighgjgj fkf
                   
    \chapter{One short line}        
    \LaTeX{} has many symbols at its disposal. The majority of them are within the mathematical domain as shown in \eqref{eq:1} and \eqref{eq:2}. The ten special keyboard characters are: \verb|#|, \verb|$|, \verb|%|, \verb|&|, \verb|~|, \verb|_|, \verb|^|, \verb|\| and  \verb|{}|. If you simply want the character to be printed just as any other letter, include a \verb|\ | in front of the character. For example, \verb|\$| will produce \verb|$| in your output.
    The exception to the rule is the \verb|\ | itself because \verb|\\ | has its own special meaning. A \verb|\ | is produced by typing \verb|$\backslash$| in your file. 
    
    \section{Special keyboard characters}   
    Special keyboard characters dhgdgdg dgdgdgdg ggdgdgd egegegege dgddgdgd eggegegeg dgdgdgdgd egegegeg dggeieieirr tktii43iwje rfrhrhrhr gtktotyiyighgjgj fkf     
    \newpage        
    Special keyboard characters dhgdgdg dgdgdgdg ggdgdgd egegegege dgddgdgd eggegegeg dgdgdgdgd egegegeg dggeieieirr tktii43iwje rfrhrhrhr gtktotyiyighgjgj fkf     
    \newpage        
    Special keyboard characters dhgdgdg dgdgdgdg ggdgdgd egegegege dgddgdgd eggegegeg dgdgdgdgd egegegeg dggeieieirr tktii43iwje rfrhrhrhr gtktotyiyighgjgj fkf     

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using pdflatex and `\usepackage{helvet}` I fail to see any misalignment.  Try the last update wit the dot removed.

Comment: The font issue has been solved by the recently updated code. However the following 2 issues remain 1. However, long chapter headers are shifting the head rule downwards which is something I do not like. Long section headers are not causing this shifting of head rules which is good. 2. The space (in the headers) between the section number and the title seems to be a little big, is it possible to reduce it so as to match that (in the header) between the chapter number and title? Can you please assist?

Comment: @itc  Increase the `headheight`. For example `headheight = 3.5\baselineskip,`. or more if you want to have more lines in the header

Comment: @itc I do not see that effect. Just in case use the last version of my answer.

Comment: All the headrules are now inside the bottom of the header frame, thank you very much. However, the space between the last line of the long header text and the headrule is different from the space between single lined header text and the corresponding headrule. In other words, can we fix this spacing so that it remain the same for both single line (short header text) and multiline (long header text) header text?

Comment: I would really like to have a fixed spacing between header text and the headrule please.

Comment: @itc Could be a topic for another question.

Comment: Noted. Thank you very much.